# phonegap/javascript developer app error (bulksms with api)

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, phonegap

I created an app an android app (Bulk sms) using javascript, html, phone gap , the app is for an already built bulksms site.
everything went smoothly but i tried test running the app. it gives me an error (error connecting to server) when i login. index.html contains the login in form which takes the login parameters ,attaches it to the API and loads a menu.html file. but the index.html files give the above error when i try logging in

here is the index.html file code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ClicknSpread</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> 
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            // Wait for device API libraries to load
            //
            function onLoad() {
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

            }

            // device APIs are available

            function onDeviceReady() {
                // Now safe to use device APIs
                document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
                var os = device.platform;
                if(os == "Android") $(".quit").removeClass('hidden');
            }

            function onBackKeyDown() {
                // Handle the back button
                var os = device.platform;
                if(os == "Android") {
                    if(confirm('Quit '+appname+'?')) navigator.app.exitApp();
                }
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="onLoad()">
    <h1 class="title appname">Menu</h1>
    <div class="page">
        <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
        <div class="login hidden center">Contacting Server...<br /><img src="images/loading.gif" /></div>
        <div class="login">
            <div class="form-container" style="width: 65%;">
                <h3>Login</h3>

                <div class="label">Username</div>
                <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username" />

                <div class="label">Password</div>
                <input type="text" id="password" placeholder="Password" />

                <div class="button-div">
                    <a href="#" onclick="login(); return false;" class="button">Login</a>
                    <a href="register.html" class="button register hidden">Register</a>
                    <a href="#"  onclick="if(confirm('Quit '+appname+'?')){ navigator.app.exitApp(); } return false;" class="button quit hidden">Quit</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div>
    <div class="footer"></a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

here is the main.js file which has the API and domain name of the bulk sms site.etc

```
api = 'http://clickspreadsmsz.com/index.php?option=com_spc&comm=spc_api&mobi=true&';
domain = 'www.clickspreadsmsz.com';
appname = 'ClicknSpread';
xOK = 'Operation completed successfully.';
x_2904 = 'SMS Sending Failed';
x_2905 = 'Username/Pasword combination is incorrect';
x_2906 = 'Credit Exhausted';
x_2907 = 'Gateway Unavailable';
x_2908 = 'Invalid Schedule Date';
x_2909 = 'Scheduling failed.';
x_2910 = 'Invalid Username';
x_2911 = 'Invalid Password';
x_2912 = 'Invalid recipient';
x_2913 = 'Invalid Message';
x_2914 = 'Invalid Sender ID';
x_2915 = 'One or more required fields are missing';
x_101 = 'Invalid voucher';
x_102 = 'Used voucher';
x_103 = 'Unable to load voucher';
x_106 = 'Invalid group name.';
x_107 = 'Operation failed.';


$(function (){
    $('.appname').html(appname);
    $('.domain').html(domain);
    $('.footer').html('&copy; '+domain+'.All rights reserved. Contact Us on +234(0)8088996437 ,+234(0)9096669196 info@bizmarrow.com, contact@clicknspreadsms.com ');

    setFontSize();
});


function setSession(key,value){
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, value);
}

function getSession(key){
    return window.localStorage.getItem(key);
}

function unsetSession(key){
    window.localStorage.removeItem(key);
}

function clearSession(){
    window.localStorage.clear();
}
function setFontSize(){
    var fs = getSession('fontsize');
    if(fs == '' || !is_numeric(fs) || fs < 10){
        fs = 16;
        setSession('fontsize',fs);
    }
    $("html, body, .page, a, textarea, select").css("font-size", fs+"px");
    $("h1").css("font-size", Math.floor(fs*1.4)+"px");
    $("h2").css("font-size", Math.floor(fs*1.3)+"px");
    $("h3").css("font-size", Math.floor(fs*1.2)+"px");
    $("h4").css("font-size", Math.floor(fs*1.1)+"px");
    $("input").css("font-size", fs+"px");

}
function is_numeric(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

function isLoggedIn(){
    var u = getSession('username');
    var p = getSession('password');
    if(u != '' && u != undefined && p != '' && p != undefined){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function nothing(){};

function balance(){
    var u = getSession('username');
    var p = getSession('password');
    if(u != '' || u != undefined || p != '' || p != undefined){
    } else {
        logout();
    }

    $.get( api+'username='+escape(u)+'&password='+escape(p)+'&balance=true' )
    .fail(function() {
        alert( "Error connecting to server" );
      })
      .done(function(data) {
        if(data == '2905' || data == '-2905'){
            alert('Invalid username and password combination.');
            logout();
        } else {
            $(".balance").html(number_format(0+data,2));
        }
      });
}

function logout(){
    unsetSession('username');
    unsetSession('password');
    window.location = "index.html";
}
```

AND this is the index.js file code which should load the menu.html file , if successfully connected to the API.

```
$(function (){
    $.get( api+'regMobile=check' )
    .done(function(data) {
        if(data == 'Enabled') $('.register').show(300);
    });
});

function login(){
    $('.login').toggle();
    var username = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    if(username == '') {
        alert('Username is required');
        $('.login').toggle();
        return;
    }
    if(password == '') {
        alert('Password is required');
        $('.login').toggle();
        return;
    }
    $.get( api+'username='+escape(username)+'&password='+escape(password)+'&balance=true' )
    .fail(function() {
        alert( "Error connecting to server" );
      })
      .done(function(data) {
        if(data == '2905' || data == '-2905'){
            alert('Invalid username and password combination.');
            logout();
        } else {
            setSession('username',username);
            setSession('password',password);
            $('.login').toggle();
            window.location = 'menu.html';
        }
      });
}

if(isLoggedIn() == true){
    window.location = 'menu.html';
}
```

here is the config.xml file code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id          = "com.smsportalcreator.demo"
        versionCode = "4" 
        version     = "4.0.0" >

    <!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <name>ClicknSpread</name>
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <description>
        Mobile App for sending Bulk sms.
    </description>
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.5" source="npm" />

    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" spec="2.3.0" source="npm"/>
    <author href="http://smsportalcreator.com" email="uchejesse126@gmail.com">
        JESSE CODERS 
    </author>

</widget>
```

i think every thing is in order but still i get that error(error connecting to server) after i built with phonegap. if more files are need i could add them . Pls help how do i resolve the error and allow smooth connecting and loading.

Comment: Have you checked console ?? can you post which error you are getting in console ?

Comment: attach here your config.xml file also

Comment: OK will update it with the config.xml file

Comment: i have added the config.xml file